# vue styling in view does not apply to html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have set up a new project with vue3. I started working with some package implementations but then I realized my CSS written in component is not applied in HTML. Here is a very simple view example

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="asd">Hello</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.asd {
  color: purple;
}
</style>
```

In the result, the text is not purple.
I have checked if it is overridden by some other css but no, it does not event show up in the styles screen of dev tools:

[image: ss of the styles]

What I have tried and checked:

- I have tried writing style as "p.asd {..." and adding an `!important` in the end. No change.
- I have checked if I am working on the correct page by changing the text from "Hello" to "Hello World" and it changes, so I am working on the correct page.
- I got a production build if it is a dev env issue, but no, got the same result from the built html.
- I have tried moving CSS to `App.vue` instead, and surprisingly styling written there works but not in the views.
- I have tried on a new browser for caching issues, no change.
- I have tried adding scoped, no change.
- I have tried adding script tags, no change. Script tags work fine, console.log script works, but still no styling update.
- I have tried inline CSS and it works.

Here is my package.json:

```
  "name": "new-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.36",
    "vue": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.0",
    "vue-tel-input": "^8.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.11.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "vite": "^4.3.5",
    "vite-plugin-webfont-dl": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/ihsanser/vue-vite-style-bug/tree/master

I don't know if I am missing something very simple, but I could not figure out the reason for hours now.

Comment: Missing script section?

Comment: try hard refresh or try with add <style scoped>

Comment: @J.Titus I don't need it for this simple setup but anyways I have added script tags but no change in the styling. script tags works fine, tested it with a console log.

Comment: @Usman also tried adding scoped no change. Refresh does not help, I even tried on a new browser.

Comment: inline css is working?

Comment: Yes, inline works.

Comment: What you showed so far [works as expected](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kU1OxDAMha8SZTObaSIxu1JGg9hwiGxKa6CQH8tOi9Cod8dpAZVBmp3t95xPeT7re0QzjaBr3XBHA2bFkEc8ujgETJTVQwqonikFtTO2NMW+c9HFxq4b4pUmQ0DfZpBOqWbZslI39lfQe72+WYUWzRunKNRzsbtvgZ2u1TIpM+GU3unXnJFra8eI7y+mS8GeRLM0xjwEqPoUTgdzMDe2HzhvxwY4VE+UPhhIgE7vN29bGU5AFUHsgYCusi68W96F9I9ZkLOLs3z/J76S9t+8+mFaCilRdb5lvnO65d7p4yN4nxpbTiKqMItzE+uSPudPX0ojO2uCXfKJaoUjoYdb4S8HW2x6/gLpUa1r). Consider providing a *rummable* [mcve] making sure it features the bug. I suggest using codesandbox.io (which allows importing a project) or a similar service.

Comment: @tao here is a codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/ihsanser/vue-vite-style-bug/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space character used in `.asd {` is not an actual space. It is a [NBSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) ***<sup>1</sup>***.

Replace it with an actual space and everything will work as expected. This is not related to Vue, the behavior would be the same in React, Angular, Svelte or vanilla.

[See it working](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cold-silence-sezy44?file=%2Fsrc%2Fviews%2FSignup.vue%3A8%2C6).

In your question, you posted the code with a space. Not sure if this is due to the NBSP > Space conversion made by the browser when rendering the current page's HTML or if you simply didn't copy/paste the code in question.
I suspect it's the first.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - encoding NBSP outputs `%C2%A0`, whereas encoding a normal space outputs `%20`

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted the code from VScode and probably it is changed during render. Thank you very much for your answer, it works now.